# Idiomatic Kotlin regexes

Tags: kotlin

Is there a nicer looking form of Kotlin regex matching with destructuring?

```
val text = """
        a
        10 rows; 120 columns
        b
        """

val columns = "(\\d+) rows; (\\d+) columns".toRegex(RegexOption.MULTILINE).find(text)?.destructured?.let { (height, width) ->
  width.toIntOrNull()
} ?: 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best option is to not use destructured and instead use

```
val matchResult = "(\\d+) rows; (\\d+) columns".toRegex(RegexOption.MULTILINE).find(output)
return matchResult?.groupValues?.get(2)?.toIntOrNull() ?: 80
```